# Installing Laravel 5 on shared cpanel hosting

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I followed [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsgWKuGk3yM) tutorial for installing Laravel 5 on a shared cpanel hosting. Everything went smooth, but I get an error when I open my website:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@naxon.co.il to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
> trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. Apache/2.4.18
> (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at naxon.co.il
> Port 80

This is how my log file looks like:

> [Sat Apr 09 00:36:06 2016] [error] [client *] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/naxond/laravel/public/index.php" is writeable by group
>
> [Sat Apr 09 00:36:06 2016] [error] [client *] Premature end of script headers: index.php

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the server's PHP version on the server! You also need to install ```php_mbstring.dll``` exstension, which can only be done by re-installing or upgrading. This can only be done by a sys-admin.

Comment: Unix path, but `.dll` extension. What the hell? Also, did you read the message at all before posting here?

Comment: @AshleyWrench triple lol. What about php_mbstring.dll... message it's very, very clear.  SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/naxond/laravel/public/index.php" is writeable by group

Comment: @abkrim he edited his question after I made that comment...perhaps you should look at the edit log.

Comment: response__> /home/naxond/laravel/public/index.php Your apache+PHP it's on mode SuPHP or fcgi, and your file are worng permission. Must be 644 or 640 or 440... chmod 640 /home/naxond/laravel/public/index.php...it's possible there're more file with same problems

Comment: If there more.. find /home/naxond/laravel/public/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; find /home/naxond/laravel/public/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the file permissions from '**0664**' to '**0644**'. It's complaining because that file (or folder) is writable by group and needs corrected to more secure permissions.

Comment: Worked. Needed to change the whole Laravel folder permissions to 755.

Answer (score 2):

Before upload your project, you must to be sure that the server match the following requirements:

- PHP >= 5.5.9
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension

As you can see in your logs, all the erros are related with the server requirements:

- Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mbstring.dll' you don't have Mbstring PHP Extension installed.
- Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll, you don't have OpenSSL PHP Extension

and so on.

You can check all the laravel requirements in their documentation.

[Laravel 5 DOC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#server-requirements)

Anyway, you can try to install the libraries if you have full access to the server.

Regards!

Comment: I Installed mbstring, open ssl, the required php version is installed... And I still get this error.

Comment: Check if the installing has  done correctly . You can write "phpinfo() ;"  in a php file and check the modules.

Comment: Check the response or Ryan or trinvh . Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Change public/index.php file permissions from **0664** to **0644**